# is it mandatory to download and install android sdk for eclipse or not?

Tags: android, eclipse

**is it mandatory to download and install android sdk for eclipse or not?** I have tried to install android studio but my program won't run.

Comment: Explain your issue in detail. If you want to develop an Android application in eclipse you should install android SDK. I would recommend you to use Android studio instead of eclipse

Comment: it is not mandatory, but you won't be able to do anything without it (obviously)

Answer (score 0):

Are you new to Android development if so please try to use Android Studio Where in you don't want to install Android SDK separately.
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Comment: yeah, i am new to Android Development and i have installed Android Studio, but when i run my application it shows gradle project sync failed and also pallete option is also disabled in Android studio.

Comment: Can you Please Post the Error you get while syncing